# Proving with epsilon for a continuous function

Tags: calculus

> Let f be a continous function in the section $[0,1]$.
>
> $f(x)>x \ \ \forall x\in[0,1]$.
>
> Prove that $\exists\epsilon>0 \ s.t \ f(x)>x+\epsilon :\ \forall x\in[0,1]$

From $f(x)>x$ I know that f is monotone increasing. So $\forall \delta>0 \ |x-y|<\delta$ and $\forall \epsilon>0 \ |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Though I have a feeling that this doesn't involve delta. How should I continue from here ?

Maybe this have something to do with intermediate value theorem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g:[0,1]\rightarrow\Bbb{R},g(x)=f(x)-x$ is continuous and positive on the $compact$ interval $[0,1]$, which means it actually achieves a minimum at some point in $[0,1]$. Can you see how to choose your $\epsilon$ now?

Comment: I saw the epsilon from the linked question but I don't understand how the minimum helps or why its divided by 2.

Comment: The minimum, say $m$, is the smallest value that $f(x)-x$ takes on, i.e. for all $x$, $x+m\leq f(x)$. So for any positive number less than $m$ (wink $\epsilon=m/2$ wink), you have $x+\epsilon<f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

$x\mapsto f(x)-x$ is continuous and assumes its minimum on the compact set $[0,1]$, which must be positive.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how does the minimum helps in this case ?